# How to filter rows in SQL EAV model?

Tags: t-sql, entity-attribute-value

I got a EAV SQL table which contains a list of preferences used for the display of a GUI. Each preference is represented by a row in the table.

I need to filter these rows to have only one row per different `ColumnName/key` column combination. If the `ID_UserPersonal` column is not NULL, it means that the row represents a user-specific preference which must have precedence over the default ones (when `ID_UserPersonal` is NULL). In that case, the default preference must be filtered out and the user-defined one must be kept for that `ColumnName/key` column combination.

[image: Data Rows]

Comment: What shoud be the result? (you can simply state the line numbers starting with 1)

Comment: Be sure to check out my updated question. I clarified some points.

Comment: Why are you storing both? If I add a prference shouldn't any existing prefernces or default preferences be deleted or at least marked as inactive?

Comment: @asmo one more question, what does uniquelly identify each row?

Comment: @aF : There's an unique row primary key, (an int) but it's hidden in the screenshot I took.

Comment: @HLGEM : Because the user is able to delete his preference, and therefore we need to be able to revert back to the default setting.

Comment: I would do that through a trigger and thus any deletes of preference would automatically add the default. That way you have a smaller table to query as well as there are many fewer records. ANd it makes the query less complicated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rank rows by `ID_Personal` putting NULLs after non-NULL values, then select the rows where ranking values are `1`, something like this:

```
;
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rnk = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY ID_Role, Section, GridName, ColumnName, [key]
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID_Personal IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, DateCreated
    )
  FROM AnEAVTable
)
SELECT *  /* or specify your columns explicitly, which is even better */
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Please pay attention to the `PARTITION BY` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in my example, in case I added too much (or, perhaps, too few) columns there.

References:

- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)
- [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example of what you need:

```
create table #t(
f1 int null,
f2 int null,
f3 int null)

insert into #t values (1,2,3), (1,2,null), (1,3,null)



--select the not null
select t.* from #t t
where t.f3 is NOT NULL
UNION ALL
--union with the NULL not present in the previously select
select t.* from #t t
inner join (select convert(varchar,f1) + convert(varchar,f2) r
            from #t where f3 is not null) a
            on a.r <> convert(varchar,t.f1) + convert(varchar,t.f2)


drop table #t
```

You'll need to make the concatenation of the fields that uniquelly identify a row on your table.